# How can I update maven version 2.x to a newest version?

Tags: java, maven

there is anyway to update maven version in cmd?

I have installed maven2.x and i want the newest version, i have been looking for and I've found sth like this:

```
one:convert convert a Maven 1 project.xml (v3 pom) to a Maven 2 pom.xml (v4 pom).
one:deploy-maven-one-repository deploy an artifact into a Maven 1 remote repository.
one:install-maven-one-repository install an artifact into the Maven 1 local repository.
one:maven-one-plugin package a Maven 1 plugin.
```

some of this sentence update my maven version?

ty for advance.

Comment: No, you just download Maven 3.1 and install it.

Comment: ' i have been looking for **anf ai** found **sth** like this' - Could you please elaborate the bold words a bit more?

Comment: sorry, my english and mecanografy are an aunthentic shit. I hope apologize me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maven has no command to upgrade to Maven 3.X. 
You should download and extract new version.

Answer (score 4):

Download the latest Maven version and add the *{installation folder}/bin* to your Path.

Comment: ty for answering, but is my last solution. i want to update by cmd not download and install, i know i'm too old and stickler.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible in Windows. In Linux you could use apt or other package manager.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff you've quoted is for converting Maven 1.x projects to 2.x and in `project.xml` to `pom.xml`. Maven 1.x project files were written in Jelly, which is a whole different thing. Maven 2.x turned the build logic into fully-Java written plugins.

So, to clear things out -- there are two things:

- If you want to upgrade to a newer version of Maven, you need to download it from [Maven's site](http://maven.apache.org/), or use a package manager such as `apt`, or whatever your distribution uses.
- If you would like to migrate your projects from Maven 2.x to 3.x, this should normally work out of the box, unless you have a) your own custom plugins, or b) third-party plugins which depend on Maven 2.x API-s, which contain deprecated stuff. Normally, things will work out of the box for you. For more details on changes, you can always check the [release notes](http://maven.apache.org/release-notes-3.x.html).